# How to clear flex shared objects when browser closes abruptly?

Tags: apache-flex, object, shared

How to clear the shared objects when user closes the browser abruptly?If the user opens the same application in two tabs, and user tries to close any one of the tab, we have to listen only the closed tab event.

Is there any ways..

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking.

If you want to clear something every time the user closes the browser; then why would you want to store that value as a [shared object](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Shared+Objects)?  The purpose of a Shared Object is to persist between sessions, or uses, of the application.

If you're using Shared Object as a generic term to mean some "Stored State" in the flex app; then it will go away at the same time the browser is closed.

If you're using shared object as a generic term to mean some a server side session, then that session should automatically time out on the server, irregardless of what happens in the browser.  Most application servers I have used provide a way to execute code when a session timeouts.

Comment: Yes, I am using shared objects to "Store State" in the flex app.But when i close the browser, still the shared objects are available.

Comment: What i am trying to achieve is, when we close the browser, the shared objects(we are storing some state information of the flex app) also should vanish.

Comment: Actually we need to hold the shared object on refresh of application but when the browser closes we want to destroy shared objects, in javascript if we add a callback to flex onbeforeunload even if we refresh our shared objects will be cleared, is there anyway to achieve this? thanks in advance.

Comment: @Siva Janapati Don't use Share Objects if you don't want them to coexist when closing the browser.  I'm trying to think of a good analogy.  To me it is like asking how to keep your computer off when you press the button to turn it on.  Or how to keep someone's phone from ringing after you call them.  Or how to prevent your food from cooking after you put it in a heated oven.  I was going to suggest using ExternalInterface and the onUnload event, but you already know the problem w/ that.  I think you're stuck.